# Writing large number of records to a CSV file - Not Working

Tags: file, output, mule-studio, recordset

Background: We are building an application MuleSoft and as part of the requirement we have to write a large number of records (approx. 30K) to a csv file. Before that we need to extract the data in the forms of XML, standalone data from DB2. Then we are applying some transformation/mapping rules and then finally we are writing the data to a csv file and FTP the csv file. I am attaching the XML.

Issue: The process is hanging somewhere after processing about 2500-2600 records only. It is not throwing any error. It just stays there, it doesn't do anything. We tried options like 1. Putting the flow as part of a mule batch flow. No difference observed 2. set max error count = -1, as we found this somewhere in the blog

Please if somebody can provide any suggestion, that will be really helpful. Is there any limit in number of records while writing to a file?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd">
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration1" url="jdbc:db2://faadbcdd0017:60004/MATIUT:user=mat_adm;password=q1w2e3r4;" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <file:connector name="File" outputPattern="Carfax.csv" writeToDirectory="C:\opt\CCM\Output\IUT" autoDelete="false" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:connector name="File1" outputPattern="sample.txt" readFromDirectory="C:\opt\CCM" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <batch:job name="batch2Batch">
        <batch:input>
            <logger message="Startr&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <foreach doc:name="For Each">
                <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select MSG_ID,TEMPL_ID,MSG_DATA,EMAIL_CHNL_IND,PUSH_CHNL_IND, INSERT_TMSP,UID FROM IUT.message_master WHERE INSERT_TMSP between 
(CURRENT TIMESTAMP- HOUR (CURRENT TIMESTAMP) HOURS- MINUTE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) MINUTES- SECOND(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) SECONDS
- MICROSECOND(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) MICROSECONDS) and ((CURRENT TIMESTAMP- HOUR (CURRENT TIMESTAMP) HOURS
- MINUTE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) MINUTES- SECOND(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) SECONDS- MICROSECOND(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) MICROSECONDS) + 1 DAY) 
and SOURCE_SYS='CSS' and  ONLINE_BATCH_IND IN('Y','E') AND APPL_PROCESS_IND = 'N' with UR]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:select>
            </foreach>
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <component class="com.mule.object.transformer.Mapper" doc:name="Java"/>
                <dw:transform-message metadata:id="9bd2e755-065a-4208-95cf-1277f5643ee9" doc:name="Transform Message">
                    <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java"/>
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv separator = "|" , header = false , ignoreEmptyLine = true
---
[{
    Timestamp: payload.timeStamp,
    NotificationType: payload.notificationType,
    UID: payload.UID,
    Name: payload.messageData.firstName,
    MiddleName: payload.messageData.middleName,
    LastName: payload.messageData.lastName,
    Email: payload.messageData.email,
    HHNumber: payload.messageData.cssDataRequest.householdNumber,
    PolicyNumber: payload.messageData.cssDataRequest.policyContractNumber,
    SentDate: payload.messageData.cssDataRequest.sendDate,
    PinNumber: payload.messageData.cssDataRequest.pin,
    AOR: payload.messageData.cssDataRequest.agentOfRecord

}]]]></dw:set-payload>
                </dw:transform-message>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\opt\CCM\Output\IUT" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger message="Batch2 Completed" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>


</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Batch Processing. Inside the BatchStep keep a BatchCommit which can be used for accumulating all the records within batch. And set this attribute streaming="true" for Batch Commit block. And Your File connector should be inside Batch Commit. Let me know if this helped